# How to get a flattened tuple type of a tuple of tuples?

Tags: typescript, tuples, recursive-type

Consider I have a tuple of tuples:

```ts
type Example = [[3,5,7], [4,9], [0,1,10,9]];
```

I want to create an utility type `Flatten<T>` such that `Flatten<Example>` gives:

```ts
type FlatExample = Flatten<Example>;
// type FlatExample = [3,5,7,4,9,0,1,10,9];
```

For my use case, you can assume the tuple is nested only one level deep. The tuples can have any size.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do this you would require recursive conditional types. This will be fully supported in 4.1:

```
type Example = [[3,5,7], [4,9], [0,1,10,9]];
type Flatten<T extends any[]> = 
    T extends [infer U, ...infer R] ? U extends any[] ? [...U, ... Flatten<R>]: []: []
type FlatExample = Flatten<Example>;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20200824#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDbQLxQNrYMwA0ArAQOwC6BOALAQJyU4AMBAjGyw+QNwBQokKADFUCYMAgA7ADwAVKBDgTJAEwDOUBJJDZyAPihZeUE1HmLl6nAEtJAMwgAnKAFUqAOk+2HzgErkoAH5XBSUpKy0dAODsT3c3KDjhUXEpaV89cgAuHGzc-nBoETF4ZDRMZLFlaVKUdD1uIA)

*Edit*

Simpler version, curtesy of jcalz:

```
type Example = [[3,5,7], [4,9], [0,1,10,9]];
type Flatten<T extends any[]> = 
    T extends [any, ...infer R] ? [...T[0], ... Flatten<R>]:  []
type FlatExample = Flatten<Example>;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20200824#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDbQLxQNrYMwA0ArAQOwC6BOALAQJyU4AMBAjGyw+QNwBQokKADFUCYMAgA7ADwAVKBDgTJAEwDOUBJJDZyAPihZeUE1HmLl6nFpBUAdA4CWkgGYQATlABK5KAH4cBztZbCZGIOFRcSlpLz1yAC4TXX5waBExeGQ0TEixZWkslHQ9biA)

*/Edit*

You can hack a version even today (the extra indirection is needed to fool the compiler into allowing the recursive conditional type, conceptually this is equivalent to the simpler above version):

```
type Example = [[3, 5, 7], [4, 9], [0, 1, 10, 9]];
type Flatten<T extends any[]> = T extends [infer U, ...infer R] ? {
    1: U extends any[] ? [...U, ...Flatten<R>] : [],
    2: []
}[U extends any[] ? 1 : 2] : [];

type FlatExample = Flatten<Example>;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDbQLxQNrYMwA0UArEQOwC6R2ALEQJxU4AMRAjO61IxQNwBQoSFABiqBMGAQAdgB4AKlAhwp0gCYBnKAmkhsFAHxQsi5as04AltIBmEAE5QAqkQB0763ccAlClAD8UADe-FBhUGwAXM5KKjIWOnp+gdjuri5QaWISqrLeBn7R+gSh4QBMRRT8AL7YTrHmWon6ARFQ0WWFOHz8guDQ2cDwyGiYouKSMrLDKOgGvEA)

Just for fun, the 4.1, generalized flattening version.

```
type Example = [[3,5,7], [4,9, [10, 12, [10, 12]]], [0,1,10,9, [10, 12]]];
type Flatten<T extends any[]> = 
    T extends [infer U, ...infer R] ? 
        U extends any[] ? 
        [...Flatten<U>, ... Flatten<R>]: [U, ... Flatten<R>]: []
type FlatExample = Flatten<Example>;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.0-dev.20200824#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDbQLxQNrYMwA0ArAQOwC6BOALAQJxXYCMADFUwEyOvsfn+M2TAjwY4eUTv3IBuAFChIUAGKoEwYBAB2AHgAqUCHE1aAJgGcoCLSGzkAfFCxyorqAaMmLOAJZaAZhAATlAAqlQAdFF+gSEASuRQAPxQLm7poYbG2t7Wtokpaemu2FERquomOqH2kVEqahraOnH25ABcOOFQZQ2Vza0dOOQK4NAVwPDIaJh9TbpTKOj2MkA)

**Note**: While recursive types are more supported in 4.1, you can still run into compiler hardcoded limits, such as type instantiation depth, and total type instances (as such recursive types generate a lot of type instantiations). So use sparingly.

Comment: darn, you got here first.  a genuine recursive conditional type for 4.1!

Comment: @jcalz I've been hunting for such an answer . It's an exciting time in the ts type system 

Comment: I might have gone with `type Flatten<T> = T extends [any, ...infer R] ? [...T[0], ...Flatten<R>] : []` myself but this one also works

Comment: @jcalz added that version as well, you are right it's simpler :)

Comment: Awesome, thank you! What is the minimum TS version for the hack to work? Is it 4.0, due to `[...A, ...B]`?

Comment: @PedroA the version above yes, requires 4.0. You can probably write a helper type to merge the tuples for an equivalent effect .. But I would recommend going with 4.0 if possible.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Ok!! I am already using 4.0 so that's fine, I was asking out of curiosity. For learning purposes, could you please show how to do this helper you said for <4.0? I tried to think of a way for a while (before asking here on SO) but failed...

Comment: Hello @jcalz and @TitanCernicova-Dragomir, actually I went to use this solution now but I am getting "*error TS2574: A rest element type must be an array type.*" on the `...infer R` part. I am using TypeScript 4.0.2, what is happening?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] of that error?  Preferably with a link to a web IDE like [The TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)?  Otherwise it's hard to say what's going on

Comment: @jcalz I figured it out. It is an issue with Prettier. It is changing `...infer R` into `...(infer R)`, even in the new 2.1.0 version. I am using a `// prettier-ignore` comment for now to disable this. Thank you for all the attention! :)